# If permite executar outras linha não desejáveis

Tags: c#, .net, if

Quero fazer um programa que permita manipular e gerir a informação sobre

CDs que está armazenada num ficheiro de texto. O ficheiro deve guardar para cada CD, o nome do autor/grupo, nome do CD, ano de edição, nome da editora, total de tempo (em minutos) e número de faixas.

O `if` não funciona porque?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line;
            int valor;
            string input;
            string[] names = new string[6];
            Console.WriteLine("Escolha:\n1 - adicionar\n2 - Visualizar\n 3 - Sair");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            valor = Int32.Parse(input);
            if (valor == 1)
                Console.WriteLine("Escreva o nome do autor/grupo, nome do CD, ano de edição, nome da editora, total de tempo e número de faixas: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    names[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                }


                StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\trabalho.txt");

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    SW.WriteLine(names[i]);
                }

                SW.Close();
            if (valor == 2)

                Console.WriteLine("FICHEIRO .txt: \n");

                StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\trabalho.txt");
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            if (valor == 3)
                Console.WriteLine("Adeus");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: Nao esta a funcionar o if

Comment: Explica o comportamento que você quer e o que está acontecendo

Comment: Testei aqui e funciona exatamente como esperado. As linhas imediatamente seguintes do if (as que tem Console.WriteLine) são condicionada pelos valores corretamente (afinal, quando o if não tem { }, ele só vale para a linha seguinte). Se esperava algo de diferente, melhor [edit] a questão e explicar exatamente seu problema, para que a pergunta possa ser reaberta. A propósito, aproveite e dê uma arrumadinha na postagem se puder, fica mais fácil de ler se não misturar línguas diferentes, maiúsculas e minúsculas, e nem ficar repetindo frases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código tem vários problemas, sendo que o principal é o que o Bacco falou em comentários. Como não há chaves no bloco de comandos o `if` só executará seletivamente a primeira linha após o `if`, o resto será executado sempre. Lição a ser aprendida: sempre use chaves, mesmo que só precisa uma linha e evite confusões.

Havia alguns pequenos problemas, e outros mais graves como o fato de aceitar digitação de valores inválidos e deixar vazar memória dos *streams*.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            string[] names = new string[6];
            WriteLine("Escolha:\n1 - adicionar\n2 - Visualizar\n 3 - Sair");
            var valor = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out valor)) WriteLine("Opção inválida");
            if (valor == 1) {
                WriteLine("Escreva o nome do autor/grupo, nome do CD, ano de edição, nome da editora, total de tempo e número de faixas: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) names[i] = ReadLine();
                using var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\trabalho.txt");
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) sw.WriteLine(names[i]);
            }
            if (valor == 2) {
                WriteLine("FICHEIRO .txt: \n");
                using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\trabalho.txt")) {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) WriteLine(line);
                }
                ReadKey();
            }
            if (valor == 3) WriteLine("Adeus");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja "quase" [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7zgvDE). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zjSLiW). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/FilterData.cs). (não tem permissão para acessar a *filesystem*).